# Error Unknown Option - CustomLogReporterPath while running existing react-native app with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on a React-Native application which needs to be setup with Expo. I have followed the instructions mentioned in the following article "https://github.com/expo/xde" but still I am getting following error -

> unknown option **customLogReporterPath**

I have tried to use the **convert** command provided by expo but its not supported now. Not sure how to fix the above error. Any suggestions?

Comment: On which OS you are setting this up ?

Comment: I am setting it on Windows 10

Comment: Is the react native you are are running is primarily been created by Expo itself or its another one ? If not, have u followed these instructions ? - https://github.com/expo/xde#converting-an-existing-project-to-work-with-expo

Comment: Though I have followed the instructions, I will once again verify the above article.

Comment: I have already followed the instructions given in the article. I am still getting the above error.